# Random oracle based on SHA-256

Tags: hash, sha-256, random-oracle-model

I am given the following problem.

> Consider SHA-256 to be a random oracle in a practical application.
>   Construct an (almost) random oracle $\{0,1\}^*→\{0,1\}^{3000}$ based on SHA-256.

Does it mean that the input is any length of zeros and ones and that is should hash to a value which is 3000 digits of zeros and ones? If yes, could I just apply SHA-256 12 times, splitting the input in 12 parts and remove 72 bits, then I will get 3000 bits? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Is this a part of a HW?

Comment: @kelalaka The problem is part of a course but it is not homework for any student to hand in. The problem is an exercise and part of a course in cryptography if that counts as "homework" but I don't think so... Because HW/homework is something that a student should hand in right?

Comment: Interestingly it seems [a homework somewhere](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-sha-256-random-oracle-practical-application-10a-1t-construct-almost-radom-oracle--q29169278) but the site doesn't provide the update time.

Comment: @kelalaka My problem set from the course appears to be [publicly available](https://kth.instructure.com/files/2758346/download?download_frd=1) and it is exactly the same three exercises but my problem number is 6 instead of 10 which is on the page from your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that the input is any length of zeros and ones and that is should hash to a value which is 3000 digits of zeros and ones?

Yes, that's the meaning of $\{0,1\}^*→\{0,1\}^{3000}$. It would be better to reformulate using the usual shortcut for "digits of zeros and ones": *bits*. Also, $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all *bitstrings*.

> Could I just apply SHA-256 12 times, splitting the input in 12 parts and remove 72 bits, then I will get 3000 bits?

$256\times12-72=3000$, thus you have the domains right. But would that be indistinguishable from a random oracle¹? No. Find how you would make the distinction. Then improve that construction. Ideally, make a proof that if a method could distinguish the refined construction from a random oracle¹, then it could be turned into a method making that distinction for SHA-256.

A random oracle with $k$-bit output is an hypothetical device that accepts a bitstring as input, and

- if that bitstring was not previously submitted, draws and outputs a random bitstring in $\{0,1\}^k$
- otherwise outputs the same bitstring as it did for the previous submission of the input bitstring.

---

¹ With no way to compute SHA-256, and perhaps disregarding the length-extension property of SHA-256, and its input length limitation; some or all of these might be what the question means with *"(almost)"*.